# как наследовать имена переменных из одного файла в другой?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

У меня есть файл который записывает в данные в эксель с помощью `openpyxl`, кроме этого у меня есть файл в которой собрана форма листов эксель, также, с помощью `openpyxl`, и в этом втором файле у меня записана переменная листа эксель `Table_report = wb.create_sheet('Table report')`, как можно наследовать эту переменную в файл в котором заполняются данные, либо же как можно присвоить переменную из одного файла в другой, нужно это для того, чтобы запись производилась в уже сформированный лист?

Comment: `from другой_файл import  Table_report`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой и безопасный способ это - обернуть вашу логику в функцию и вызвать `return`

```py
# create.py - название файла 

def create_table_report():
  # какая то логика...
  table_report = wb.create_sheet('Table report')
  return table_report
```

И уже в файле в котором будете использовать результат

```py
# main.py - название файла 
from create import create_table_report

table_report = create_table_report()
```

В другом случае, если вы используете передачу переменных между своими файлами, то вы не защищены от переопределения их, что может вызывать побочные эффекты. То есть функция не будет знать, были ли изменения\переопределения в переменной и будет обрабатывать данные "как есть". А там могут вылезти и не понятные баги, не верные данные в итоговом результате и все это надо как-то обрабатывать.

Поэтому практикуется использование "чистых функций", которые ничего не изменяют и не переопределяют вне зоны своей видимости. В нее передаются данные, которые будут обрабатываться, а на выходе забирается итог обработки.

С другой стороны, вы не ограничены и спокойно можете передавать переменные между своими файлами в логике, при помощи `import`

Comment: Большое спасибо!